# How can automatic synthesize statements be applied? Is it better/worse to have them over synthesize statements?

Tags: xcode, statements, synthesize

I learned how @synthesize statements work but I run the latest version of xcode(not xcode 6 beta) and as Im learning objective-C, I found out that synthesize statements could be done automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic property synthesis was [added in Xcode 4.4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html). You can omit the `@synthesize` in almost all cases.

Comment: Is it better to omit @synthesize or refer to automatic property synthesis?

Comment: When you omit (leave out) `@synthesize`, the setter, getter, and backing ivar are automatically generated. You only need `@synthesize` in very specific circumstances, and the compiler will usually tell you when those are.